# Xamarin Forms Auto adjust elements in ScrollView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

**Xamarin Forms Version** : 2.5

Complete and partial scroll look like below :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzJIw.jpg

Height of ScrollView is 150 , and the height of each item in the scroll view is 50.

**Requirement:**
At any point in time the scroll always has to be in the complete scrolled position ie The vertical Scroll has to display only 3 items and the center item to be highlighted. If and when the items are scrolled and the number of items is anything other than 3(Partial Scroll) then the display has to auto adjust to three items.

**Problem** : There is no event on the scrollview which can be used to auto adjust the scroll.

**Code**

```
<ScrollView
            x:Name="ListScrollViewer"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackLayout x:Name="ItemsLayout" Spacing="0" />
</ScrollView>

public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
         BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemsSource), typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(VerticalScrollView), null, BindingMode.Default, null, null);

public IEnumerable ItemsSource
{
    get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
    set
    {
        SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);

        var i = 0;
        foreach (var item in value)
        {
            ItemsLayout.Children.Add(new TextView(item, i));

            var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer()
            {
                CommandParameter = i,
                Command = new Command<object>(OnTap),
                NumberOfTapsRequired = 1,
            };

            ItemsLayout.Children.Last().GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);

            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

**Scroll View Usage:**

```
<local:VerticalScrollView
        x:Name="VerticalScroll"
        BackgroundColor="Black"
        HeightRequest="150"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        VerticalOptions="Center" />
```

**Code Behind**

```
public List<object> Options { get; set; } = new List<object>(); 

Options.Add(new { Name = "Val 1" });
Options.Add(new { Name = "Val 2" });
Options.Add(new { Name = "Val 3" });
Options.Add(new { Name = "Val 4" });
Options.Add(new { Name = "Val 5" });

VerticalScroll.ItemsSource = Options;
```

Comment: Why don't you update the version of Xamarin.forms?  The latest stable version is 3.4.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT Unfortunately i cannot, as i need to use an older version of Windows 10 due to an enterprise level challenge.